# Make call from one docker container to another one

Tags: docker

So I have two different applications one wordpress and other is api. And both running on docker containers and have their own configurations. This is their `docker-compose` settings:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/php/Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - ./public:/usr/src/app/public
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - app_network

  nginx:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_nginx
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./public:/usr/src/app/public
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    expose:
      - 8081
    environment:
      NGINX_FPM_HOST: app
      NGINX_ROOT: /usr/src/app/public
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      - app_network

  db:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}_db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    networks:
      - app_network

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```

And this is my wordpress configuration:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
            - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
        expose:
            - 3306
            - 33060
        healthcheck:
            test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u $$MYSQL_USER --password=$$MYSQL_PASSWORD
            interval: 1s
            timeout: 3s
            retries: 30
        networks:
            - app_network

    wordpress:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            mysql:
                condition: service_healthy
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/name
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        restart: always
        environment:
            - WORDPRESS_URL=http://localhost
            - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql
            - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
            - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
            - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
        networks:
            - app_network

networks:
    app_network:
        driver: bridge
```

And when I try to make request to api to this URL `http://localhost:8081` well nothing happens. Locally works everything fine but on docker it doesn't.

Would appreciate some help how to make this work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a docker container and you do http://localhost:8081, you wont go to your host pc, but to the container itself.

In docker-compose you need to replace localhost with the service name:

For example if you want to access 8081 of the nginx, you need to connect to http://nginx:8081

Comment: Yea, I found out the problem. Networks were created with different prefixes so I provided the name for network